# R - New Dataframe from Column Counts?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Dog     Breed     Dog.Distraction     Resource.Guarding
1   Max     BL        N/A                 1
2   Rover   YL        1                   N/A
3   Tina    GR        1                   N/A
```

I want a new dataframe that looks like:

```
          Dog. Distraction     Resource.Guarding
Count     2                    1
```

What's the best way to do this? I can use sum() to find each individual column, but not sure how to convert to new df. Alternatively, I'm also ok with:

```
                   Count
Dog.Distraction    2
Resource.Guarding  1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `colSums` assuming the `N/A` is `NA`

```
out <- colSums(df1[c('Dog.Distraction', 'Resource.Guarding')], na.rm = TRUE)
```

If we need to change the `names`

```
names(out) <- c("V1", "V2")
```

The output of `colSums` is a named `vector`

Comment: One more thing! Is there a way to name these new columns?

Comment: @gf7 the output of `colSums` is a `named` vector.  If you need as a `data.fframe` then you need `as.data.frame.list(colSums(df1[c('Dog.Distraction', 'Resource.Guarding')], na.rm = TRUE))`